# Looking for a 60/70s book on supernatural/occult that was in a elementary school library

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, powers

It was an oversized canvas bound dark green covered book that had stories like the Mary Celeste, Sirens, coffin birth, stuff like that. It was pretty old back in the early 90s and I'm guessing it was written in at least the 70s. I cannot remember the name or author but it was about 200 pages with vivid illustrations, very dark. I don't know why it was in an elementary school in the Bay Area but I loved it and have never been able to find anything on it.

Comment: Can you describe the style of the illustrations? Color or black and white, realistic or stylized (and if stylized can you compare it to anything)?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is one of John Canning's books, possibly [50 Strange Stories of the Supernatural](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2709367) or [50 True Tales of Terror](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=30376376091).

Both were published in the 70s and had green covers. There was one drawing for each tale and they were vivid and gritty.